# Is there a way to rewind stdin in C?

Tags: c

So my code should look through a text file via command line with

```
 ./program < text.txt
```

This way of executing the program is important for my purposess.

but after going through it once every other method already looks at the end of the text file.

Im trying to go through a provided text file but once a function reads it once, probably the pointer already stays at the end of the file and other functions dont work anymore.

So there is the most basic function that uses this.
Once i try any other function with the same for cycle it just doesnt work anymore. I suppose its the pointer but i havent been successful with finding a way to refresh it.

```
void writeOut()
{
    char line[100];
    for(; fgets(line, 100, stdin) != NULL;)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"%s", line);

    }
    fprintf(stdout,"\n");
}
```

I expect to be able to read through the same file multiple times and be able to "flush" the memory of fgets().

Thanks for any useful input

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I have done that and it works, but for me its important to go with  ./program < text.txt.

Comment: Your program currently reads from `stdin` and `stdin` is a stream that cannot be rewound. If you need to process the input multiple times you can save it in a temporary file during the first processing then rewind the temporary file and read from it for each subsequent processing.

Comment: @axiac Actually, in the `./program < text.txt` case it's possible to rewind (or arbitrarily seek) on `stdin` just as if you had opened it yourself.  It's the `program2 | program1` case that's the real killer.

Comment: @LukasCu If you know you'e reading from an actual file you can use `rewind(stdin)`.  Otherwise you'll have to copy `stdin` to a temporary file, then switch to operating on that.

Comment: @SteveSummit *in the `./program < text.txt` case it's possible to rewind (or arbitrarily seek) on `stdin`* Do you know if that's  an actual POSIX requirement for the shell, or is that just a "typical" implementation?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don''t know.  The "typical implementation" is so obvious and ubiquitous it's hard for me to imagine it working any other way (i.e., not working), but that could just be because I'm so used to the obvious implementation.  Certainly the requirement that `fork` and `exec` preserve open files (and the current file position within them) is a Posix requirement.

Comment: @SteveSummit [Here's what I found](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07): "Input redirection shall cause the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for reading on the designated file descriptor"  Output redirection is similar. "the file ... shall be opened ... on the designated file descriptor".  I suspect the easiest way to detect this would be to check the return value from `lseek( STDIN_FILENO, 0, SEEK_CUR );`.  If that doesn't fail, it's seekable.  `fstat( STDIN_FILENO ...)` would probably work, too, with `S_ISREG()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I remember once convincing myself that `(lseek(0, 1, SEEK_SET) == 1)` was the best test for seekability.  (Don't remember what all the pro/con arguments were, though, and I probably wasn't considering 0-length files, either.)

Comment: What kind of problem requires you to rewind stdin? This smells bad design and [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I've changed the title. It is not the `fgets` but `stdin` that restricts things.

Comment: @axiac "stdin is a stream that cannot be rewound." is completely and utterly false.  If you execute the program where stdin is a regular file, you can seek and rewind to your heart's content.  eg `cmd < input`

Comment: @WilliamPursell it is not "completely false" at all. It is false sometimes. But one cannot rely on `stdin` as being rewindable because, in general, it is not. Sometimes it is, **if** some condition is met.

Comment: Holy hyperbole, Batman!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I shouldn't post this here, and I agree that assuming that `stdin` can't be seekable is an unfortunate misassumption, but certainly, much bigger ones are that `scanf` is a good way to read user input, that `feof` is a good way to determine whether the next input operation will succeed, and that `printf("%d %d %d\n", i, i++, ++i)` is a good way to investigate the behavior of the `++` operator...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `rewind()` and `fseek()` functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) are the conventional ways to reposition a stream **that supports doing so**.  Not all streams do support it, and whether yours does is a function not only of your C implementation but also of your operating environment and the specific circumstances of program launch.

I would generally be inclined to expect a stream associated with redirected input *not* to support repositioning, so even if it worked in your particular circumstances, you would be wise to consider a more reliable alternative.

In particular, you could create a temporary file, copy the standard input to it, and then use that file.  You can perform the copying either ahead of time or as you perform the first ordinary run-through.  If you need to re-read the data specifically from `stdin`, as opposed to from some other stream you open, then you can use [`freopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen) to attach `stdin` to your temp file.

Comment: There's no need to use a tmp file.  If you can't rewind on stdin when stdin is a regular file, then use a different platform!  I'm fairly unix-centric, and I've never seen `rewind(stdin)` fail when stdin is a regular file, so maybe my bias is coming through here.  Do non-unix platforms not allow that?!

Comment: @WilliamPursell, "use a different platform" is rarely a viable solution.  You make a fair a point, however, that my stated expectation may be unjustified for the platform of interest.  Nevertheless, the advantage of avoiding reliance on the standard input to support repositioning should not be discounted.  What if it is instead connected to a pipe or a socket?

Answer (score 1):

If stdin is a seekable file, then `rewind(stdin)` ought to work just fine.  If you need to rewind on a non-seekable file, then you either need to buffer all the data (either in memory or in a temporary file) or abort.  That is, just do:

```
if( fseek(stdin, 0L, SEEK_SET) ) {
    perror("stdin");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Hello,
I tried to use the rewind function. The txt file is in the same folder as the .c file. It executes but none of the methods seem to work anymore since the start.

Comment: I tried to add the if at the end of my function but nothing seems to be changed.

Comment: rewind() does not return a value, so it's difficult to tell if it failed. You need to clear errno and check its value.  Instead of rewind, use fseek() and check the value returned. If it failed, then stdin is (probably) not seekable.

Comment: Just for the records, `fseek(stdin, 0L, SEEK_SET)` doesn't return a non zero value in MSVC, even if `stdin` is not redirected (console input) and it obviously fails at forcing you to type the same stuff again.