# How to load a txt file through arguments without fopen? Easier way?

Tags: c

I have to load a text file with arguments. As you can see I wrote the code but I think it's ugly and long; can someone adjust it to get a better looking or at least help somehow?
I am not allowed to use fopen and the malloc family.

```c
int main (int argc, char ** argv){

    char c;
    char table[1000][1000]= {0};
    char delimiter[max_characts_in_cell];

    bool del_a =0;
    bool f_row =1;

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int numofdelim = 0;

    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"error please input arguments");
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END),ftell(stdin)) > 0){
        rewind(stdin);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr,"error file is empty");
        return 1;
    }

    delimiter[0]=' ';

    for(int i = 1; i < argc;i++){
        if(!strcmp(argv[1],"-d") && argc != i+1){
            if(strlen(argv[i+1])>max_characts_in_cell){
                fprintf(stderr,"error delimiter exceeded 30 characts");
                return 1;
            }
            strcpy(delimiter,argv[i+1]);
            del_a=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    while((c=getchar())== '\n'){
        table[row][column]=c;
        column++;
    }

    ungetc(c,stdin);

    int num_chars_between_delimiters=0;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(del_a==1 && c !=delimiter[0]){
            for(int i =1; i<max_characts_in_cell;i++){
                if(c==delimiter[1]){
                    c=delimiter[0];
                }
            }
        }

        if(c==delimiter[0]){
            num_chars_between_delimiters=0;
        }
        else{
            num_chars_between_delimiters++;
        }

        if(num_chars_between_delimiters>max_characts_in_cell){
            fprintf(stderr,"error: max number of characts in cell");
            return 1;
        }

        table[row][column]=c;
        column++;

        if(row==999||column==999){
            fprintf(stderr,"file too big");
            return 1;
        }

        if(c==delimiter[0]&& f_row==1){
            numofdelim++;
        }

        if(c=='\n'){
            f_row=0;
            row++;
            column=0;
            num_chars_between_delimiters=0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)printf("%s",table[i]);
        printf("\n rariadsad %i",row);
    return 0;
}
```

The input file (xxx.txt):

```
Cviceni:Bodu:Projekt888
Prvni programy:0:
Cyklus typy:0:
Retezce:0:
Funkce 1:0:
Struktury:2:
Ukazatele:2:
Funkce:0:Obhajoba 1
Malloc, dbg:2:
:0:
:0:
Iterace, rekurze:2:
:0:Obhajoba 2
Dynamicke struktury:2:
```

The output of the command: `CMD :xxx.exe -d : <xxx.txt`

```
same as input
```

Comment: Why "without `fopen`"?

Comment: `if(row==999||column==999){` should probably be `if(row>=999||column>=999){` given your array size.

Comment: @tadman im not allowed

Comment: If you have constraints, academic or otherwise, it's best to try and explain at least a little otherwise we'll think you're just paranoid.

Comment: @tadman yop academic constraints,i send it up front so they can say to me if its okay and they said i have to rewrite but as i said i have no idea how im new in c.Its gonna be a single  spreadsheet i hope i have a few more functions as add lines or columns or delete ... but i have to wait for these at least one more day a then if someone here its gonna help me then iam gonna adjust the functions

Comment: It looks like you've just gone at it here and smashed out a bunch of code without any real plan, but that's understandable if you're learning. I'd suggest trying to break this up into smaller, more easily tested functions. Jamming everything into `main()` is not sustainable. Once you have simpler functions, ideally where each has [one purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), you'll be able to confirm that each is working properly before moving on to integrating them.

Comment: @tadman thx for the advise, i have a few more weeks before the deadline so i gonna try it your way split it in the more functions

Answer (score 1):

At least these issues:

- `rewind(stdin);` --> see [Is there a way to rewind stdin in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58671330/2410359)
- Off by 1: `if(strlen(argv[i+1])>max_characts_in_cell){` --> `>=`.
- `char c; ... (c=getchar())!=EOF`  --> Use `int c;` to distinguish correctly the 257 different return values of `getchar()`.