# check for whitespace characters at the beginning of an input

Tags: c, validation, scanf

I need to validate an input for any invalid characters including the whitespace characters using scanf() result.

I have written this function:

```
bool is_input_valid(double* inp_ptr) {
bool isInputValid = false;
char newline = 0;
int result = scanf("%lf%c", inp_ptr, &newline);
rewind(stdin);
if (result == 2 && newline == '\n') {
   isInputValid = true; 
}
else {
   printf("Error! Invalid input format!\n");
   rewind(stdin);
}
return isInputValid;
}
```

the problem is that it does not work for spaces at the beginning of the input (so when I type [ 134] it is considered as a valid input). How can I modify my function to handle this case?

Comment: Input with `fgets()` to make things easier.

Comment: You should use `fgets` and check that string before potentially parsing it with `sscanf`.

Comment: You might find that `stdin` cannot take a `rewind`. See [Is there a way to rewind stdin in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670828/is-there-a-way-to-rewind-stdin-in-c)

Comment: Are you aware how the format specifier you selected causes the white-space-ignoring? If not read up.

Answer (score 4):

Like many `scanf` specifiers, `%lf` consumes and discards any and all leading white space characters, which makes this cumbersome to detect by using *only* `scanf`. In general, using `scanf` is also likely to leave your input stream in a poor state.

(*Aside: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)*)

The general advise, is that you are better off reading an entire line of input into a buffer with `fgets` and using `strtod` to parse the value, which gives more control and provides more robust error handling.

`strtod` *does* allow optional leading whitespace (categorized by `isspace`), so this will be need to be explicitly checked.

A fairly complete example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool is_input_valid(double *inp_ptr) {
    char buffer[4096];

    /* EOF / input error, or leading white space */
    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) || isspace((unsigned char) *buffer))
        return false;

    char *endp;
    errno = 0;
    double value = strtod(buffer, &endp);

    if (inp_ptr)
        *inp_ptr = value;

    /* value did not go out of range,
     * something was parsed, and
     * parsing was terminated by LF or null-byte
     */
    return ERANGE != errno && buffer != endp && ('\n' == *endp || !*endp);
}

int main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        double value;

        printf(":: ");

        if (is_input_valid(&value))
            printf("-> %lf\n", value);
        else {
            if (ferror(stdin) || feof(stdin))
                break;

            puts("-> invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

```
:: abc
-> invalid input
:: 123.456abc
-> invalid input
::     123.456
-> invalid input
:: 123.456
-> 123.456000
:: 0x123
-> 291.000000
::
```

I would be inclined to separate I/O and validation, though.

Comment: 1) "inclined to separate I/O and validation" is good!  2) Good use of `|| !*endp`  3) Detail:  `ERANGE != errno` is a problem with `strtod()` when the value is tiny (subnormal).  When input would convert to a value  (0 ... `DBL_MIN`), `errno` _may_ become `ERANGE`.  Most code tolerates input converting to a value in the [`DBL_TRUE_MIN` and `DBL_MIN`] range, even if `errno` is set.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to validate an input for any invalid characters including the whitespace characters using scanf() result.

- Using `fgets()` is a better approach.
- Do not use use `rewind(stdin);` as that is *undefined behavior* (UB).
- If you *must* use `scanf()`, use `" "` to skip optional whitespace and use `"%n"` to count the scanned characters.  These 2 scan specifiers never fail.

```
int n = 0;
int result = scanf(" %n%lf%c", &n, inp_ptr, &newline);
//rewind(stdin);
if (n == 0 && result == 2 && newline == '\n') {
   isInputValid = true; 
}
```

--

**Advanced**

- Input like "123.45" then end-of-file is usually considered valid input too.
- Overflow/underflow on input with `"%f"` and friends is strictly problematic, yet most systems handle this without issue.
- `"%lf"` and `" %n%lf"` both allow multiple `'\n'` before reading `stdin`.  Hence the preference for `fgets()`.
- When input is ill-formed `scanf()`, as answered here, *detects* issues, yet `stdin` is not always left in a clear state as to what is left to read in the line.  Recall `rewind(stdin);` is UB.  Another reason for `fgets()`.